# PHP .htaccess RewriteRule allow multiple combination

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my .htaccess file.

In my .htaccess rules if I put this:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)$ /the_post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I'll be able to navigate url like this:
*http://www.example.com/post/12*
But if I try:
*http://www.example.com/post/12/*
or
*http://www.example.com/post/12/something-else-here*
The page was not founded.

What is the right way to allow any possible combinations of url?

- http://www.example.com/post/12
- http://www.example.com/post/12/
- http://www.example.com/post/12/something-else-here

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current rule :

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)$ /the_post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

You can't have any `/` after `post/` in your url. `[^/]*` means any character except `/`.

You can try this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+) /the_post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to replace your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)(/[^/]*)?/?$ the_post.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```